# Getting error when importing fontawesome icons

Tags: typescript, node-modules, commonjs, astrojs, esmodules

I'm trying to build a simple website using Astro, it runs perfectly fine when using `astro dev` but I can't build the website using `astro build` because this happens:

The error I'm getting:

```
error   Named export 'faGithub' not found. The requested module '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
  CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:
  
  import pkg from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
  const { faGithub, faLinkedin, faDiscord } = pkg;
```

Here's my code:

```
import {
    faGithub,
    faLinkedin,
    faDiscord,
} from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";
```

Here's my `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "types": ["astro/client"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have been trying to find a solution for this also.

Here is the related bug report:
https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/pull/19041

For a quick try if you add "type":"module" into the node_modules/@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/packages.json build works.

Fix will be included in the next release of the package as mentioned in the bug report. For now I use a dirty hack that changes the free-brand-svg-icons' packages.json file with sed before building.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Astro Icons?](https://github.com/natemoo-re/astro-icon)
Itś already optimized and you can import all icons from many libraries, including fontawesome as you can see at [the icon sets](https://icon-sets.iconify.design/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33396877)

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue, I used fontawesome icon in the component library built by Vite and the package.json -> type:'module' declaration was missing after compiling at packaging time.

If you use it in the component library, you can solve it by adding `external: [..., '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome', '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons']` to the vite/rollup build options